# Div not displaying using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document-ready

I have the below which is supposed to change the div depending on the image link clicked.

I want the British content to show automatically on page load, then it gives the option to change the div to display different content (language) by clicking on the image of the flag.

This works in jsFiddle and CodePen but is not working on my site, even when using the exact same code. Whenever I click the Iranian logo it does not load the content.

Any tips?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wayfindermenu a').click(function(e) {
        hideContentDivs();
        var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
        $('.maincontent div').eq(tmp_div).show();
    });

    function hideContentDivs() {
        $('.maincontent div').each(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }

    hideContentDivs();
    $('.maincontent div').eq(0).show();
});

$(function() {
    $('#wayfindermenu li a').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pxce3t31/

Comment: First job when debugging Javascript; check the console for errors.

Comment: Is your site importing jquery? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Maybe you are using differents jquery versions + check F12 / Console

Comment: Maybe you have twice the same ID in your website and it screw up jQuery.

Comment: Just checked the console and no errors on page load or when clicking on the buttons... It seems that when I click the british logo, it makes the content div active and the others hidden. However, when I click the iranian logo, it takes away the active and makes them both hidden rather than making the iranian content active

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache of your browser?

Comment: This is the page where it isn't working:
https://www.herts.ac.uk/tim-test-site/test-7-flag-changer

Comment: Check the content of your `tmp_div` when you click on the Iran flag. I bet the condition `$('.maincontent div').eq(tmp_div)` returns false for some reason. (What I'm sure about is that the `<div id="page2" class="content" style="display: none;">` stay hidden even when you click on the Iran button, so it's likely due to the fact that the previous condition is evaluated to false)

Comment: you dont have `$('.maincontent div').eq(0).show();` in your page code to set the default to show the first div content, but you have it in the fiddle

Comment: @indubitablee Indeed. So that there isn't any default div displayed. But that doesn't explain why it doesn't work when clicking on the image itself, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason, the code `$('.maincontent div').eq(1);` is bringing back the image of your flag instead of your iran content.
(`div class=​"image right" style=​"display:​ block;​">​<img src=​"https:​/​/​www.herts.ac.uk/​__data/​assets/​image/​0008/​24983/​Iran.jpg" alt=​"Flag of Kuwait">​</div>​`)

try this implementation instead - target the specific class of the content instead of using indexes:

use `data` tag attributes to link which flag link goes with which page id, then target that specific `div` content and show it.

and also, britain doesnt show as default in your page because you dont have `$('.maincontent div').eq(0).show();` in your page code, but its in your fiddle. you can also target the specific britain div like i did below `$('page1').show();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    hideContentDivs();
    $('#page1').show();
    
    $('#wayfindermenu a').click(function(e){
        hideContentDivs();
        var target = $(this).data('page'); // gets the data-page attribute
        $('#' + target).show(); // shows the page
    });
 
    function hideContentDivs(){
        $('.maincontent div').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="wayfindermenu">
    <li id="link1" class="">
        <a href="#!" data-page="page1">
            <img src="https://www.herts.ac.uk/__data/assets/image/0005/104909/english.svg.png" alt="Britain flag logo" id="itemImg"/>
        </a>  
    </li>
    <li id="link2" class="active">
        <a href="#!" data-page="page2">
            <img src="https://www.herts.ac.uk/__data/assets/image/0020/104906/Flag_of_Iran.svg.png" alt="Iran flag logo" id="itemImg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="maincontent">
    <div id="page1">british content</div>
    <div id="page2">iran content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works great thanks! the only part that isn't working is making the a class active (which adds the bottom margin to the flag so you know which one is selected). I am guessing I can throw in the 
$(function() {
    $('#wayfindermenu li a').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });

to your answer?

Comment: yea, was just showing you an simple example. the adding of the class 'active' code should work with my code. if it doesnt, let me know

Comment: Hi Indubitablee,

Do you know why the code above hides the images that are supposed to be displayed? e.g. on this page 
https://www.herts.ac.uk/tim-test-site/test-7-flag-changer

there is supposed to be a large flag within the content...and when you inspect it the image is there but with a display:hidden but nothing in the code it set to display that?